# Limit for iOS Sync: iOS app Crashes when Syncing reaches over 200 MB

Tags: ios, sharepoint, crash, synchronization

Is there a limit on the amount of data a single web service can transfer to a native iPad app?  My developer is building an iPad app that connects to Sharepoint via a Restful Webservice.  When we attempt to sync the app with the document repository, the app crashes at 250 MB almost exactly each time.

Wondering if there is a limit I am dealing with or if we are doing something wrong in our approach.

Thanks
DK

Comment: Do you have any clues *why* it crashes?

Comment: Are you releasing the memory you are allocating, what does instruments say?

Comment: It runs out of memory.  I put it on instruments and it predictably crashes at about 350MB of ram.

Comment: We are not releasing the memory until after the sync process on a single web service completes.  Its downloading about 500 MB of data (video files, PDFs and .DOCx files).

Comment: I am not the developer, but I will have her chime in with more info.  Thanks so much for your help so far...

Answer (score 1):

What I am guessing is that you ran out of memory. From what your saying I'm guessing that you have an iPad 1 / 2? The reason this happens is you are *not* writing it at say 5MB intervals, you are storing it all in the iPads **ram** so once it your app runs out of ram the iPad quits the application so that the entire app doesn't freeze up.

Comment: You are right.  I am going to have my developer chime in here with more detailed information...